# How can I prevent username and password from being displayed when my impersonation account is locked?

Tags: asp.net

I'm currently hosting a web application written in VB.NET 4. the app uses impersonation which stores a username and password in the web.config. My problem is when the impersonate account is locked (which takes down the site), the site displays an error page with a stack trace revealing the username and password in clear text.

Custom error messages are set to off so I'm not sure why this is happening.  I don't have the option of encrypting this portion of the web.config because we have a staging server that replicates to the production server, and the encryption keys are different on each server.

Entry in the web.config that is being displayed:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="test\myservice.account" password="123"/>
<machineKey validationKey="11111111" decryptionKey="222222222" validation="SHA1"/>
```

Comment: You might want to try and avoid impersonation altogether. It is (usually) a bad idea to use it with web applications.

Comment: @blueberryfields why is that? How would you control resource access?

Comment: It (usually) has unexpected and considerable implications when you try to scale, or properly secure your application. I prefer to rely on explicit resource access control schemes. What kind of resource access problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stated that custom errors mode is off, which means you'll see web.config output. Set custom errors to true, specify the error page, and then you shouldn't see web.config output.

Comment: Thanks. I set customerrors to mode="remoteOnly" and pointed the default redirect to a custom error page.

Comment: Do note that the difference between "Remote Only" and "True" is that true will show custom errors for everyone. Remote only will show custom errors for everyone except the server. I can see remote being helpful in instances where you want to just pull up the page on the server to see the error before editing on a dev machine... however you really should be getting either emails of errors or setting up an error framework such as ELMAH.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably encrypt that portion of your configuration.

[Encrypting Configuration Information Using Protected Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53tyfkaw.aspx)

or alternatively create a separate application pool for your site to run in and set the identity of the application pool.

Comment: thanks...i'll look into the app pool option and see if that does the trick. due to the server environment i can't use aspnet_regiis.